# How to check if the parameter of a statistical model is identified?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, identifiability

I understand the definition of identifiability but I'm not sure how to check for it.

Could I just take the expectation of the distribution with two different parameters and show they are different in order to show the parameter is identified?

Comment: What model do you have in mind? Are you thinking of Structural Equations Models (SEM)?

Comment: Just a general statistical model for a statistical experiment. As in a pair describing the sample space and the probability distribution of the observations of the experiment.